# How do I open folders in new windows/tabs by default in the Finder in 10.9?

Tags: finder, macos

In 10.9 Mavericks the default for the Finder is to now open the selected folder in the same window instead of a new tab or window. How do I go back to the old behavior where a new window (or tab) is opened for each folder?

Answer (score 3):

The closest solution is to go to **Finder Preferences > General**, uncheck the "Open folders in tabs instead of new windows" option, and then use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + double click to open in a new window.

Source: [Apple Support Communities - Mavericks Finder - how default to "double click opens new window"?](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23471810#23471810)

Answer (score 3):

3 ways:

- Close sidebar, right click tool bar in window and "hide". Now you can double-click to open.
- Command-click folder
- Turn on right button clicking for the mouse in System Preferences. Then right click for sub menu and "open in new window"

Comment: This first suggestion helps/works and is what I came here looking for, though to clarify it's even easier than this: any Finder window that doesn't have the sidebar has the old (better) behavior of opening in a new window (if the Preferences are set properly), and CMD Option T is the shortcut. Happily, 10.9 seems to do a good job of remembering Window settings as well, so once the sidebar is hidden then the window should work properly from then on.